# Why gatling project don't work with maven?

Tags: maven, gatling, scala-gatling, gatling-plugin, maven-gatling-plugin

I am starting with gatling, I have a project with maven with the latest versions of gatling and scala, I have already checked all the parameterization within the ide I have changed versions and nothing works

here show my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>gatling-poc</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>14</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>14</maven.compiler.target>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>

        <gatling.version>3.8.4</gatling.version>
        <gatling-maven-plugin.version>4.2.7</gatling-maven-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.gatling.highcharts</groupId>
            <artifactId>gatling-charts-highcharts</artifactId>
            <version>${gatling.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
                <artifactId>gatling-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${gatling-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.gatling.core.check.FindCheckBuilder
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/gatling/core/check/FindCheckBuilder
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
    at io.gatling.app.Selection$Selector.$anonfun$singleSimulationFromConfig$2(Selection.scala:76)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:210)
    at io.gatling.app.Selection$Selector.findUserDefinedSimulationInClassloader$1(Selection.scala:76)
    at io.gatling.app.Selection$Selector.$anonfun$singleSimulationFromConfig$4(Selection.scala:91)
    at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:477)
    at io.gatling.app.Selection$Selector.$anonfun$singleSimulationFromConfig$3(Selection.scala:91)
    at scala.Option.flatMap(Option.scala:283)
    at io.gatling.app.Selection$Selector.singleSimulationFromConfig(Selection.scala:90)
    at io.gatling.app.Selection$Selector.$anonfun$selection$1(Selection.scala:52)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:201)
    at io.gatling.app.Selection$Selector.selection(Selection.scala:44)
    at io.gatling.app.Selection$.apply(Selection.scala:36)
    at io.gatling.app.Runner.run(Runner.scala:49)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.start(Gatling.scala:91)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.fromArgs(Gatling.scala:53)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.main(Gatling.scala:41)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling.main(Gatling.scala)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at io.gatling.plugin.util.MainWithArgsInFile.runMain(MainWithArgsInFile.java:53)
    at io.gatling.plugin.util.MainWithArgsInFile.main(MainWithArgsInFile.java:34)
```

How do I resolve this?

I hope your help, please

Answer (score 1):

`<testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>` seems to indicate you want to write your Gatling Simulations in Scala.

But then you haven't configured the `scala-maven-plugin` to compile your Scala code.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/gatling/core/check/FindCheckBuilder

This class no longer exists in modern Gatling version. There's no way you get this error if your code was indeed compiled with Gatling 3.8.4 in the classpath.

In short, because you haven't configured the `scala-maven-plugin`, your Scala code is not being recompiled after you upgraded your dependencies.

Please check the official samples (and generally speaking the official documentation):

- Java: https://github.com/gatling/gatling-maven-plugin-demo-java
- Scala: https://github.com/gatling/gatling-maven-plugin-demo-scala

Comment: I removed gatling core from my .m2, but when I run again after downloading the gatling core dependency, I get the same error

Comment: configure the scala-maven-plugin on your project like demoed in the sample and perform a mvn clean first